# I have error in my android application class Im checking auth != null but still its go inside that if statement?

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-authentication

My application class like below when I logout from application and try to login this happens

```
public class WhatsApp extends Application {

        private DatabaseReference userReference;
        private FirebaseAuth auth;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(this);
            builder.downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            Picasso built = builder.build();
            built.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
            built.setLoggingEnabled(true);
            Picasso.setSingletonInstance(built);

            if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance() != null) {

                userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot != null) {
                            userReference.child("online").onDisconnect().setValue(false);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Im getting an error like below

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.example.crowderia.whatsapp.Service.WhatsApp:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4999)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:188)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1591)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.crowderia.whatsapp.Service.WhatsApp.onCreate(WhatsApp.java:39)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)

Comment: See my answer bellow. Let me know if it solved the crash

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {    

} else {
    goLogInScreen();
}
```

Try that instance of

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance() != null
```